# DSpace Internal error when I change language

Tags: dspace

I've installed DSpace 6.3 but when I change language to spanish, translation works but throws me an internal error at home page. If I switch back to English it works good.
I've changed it at my dspace.cfg\

`default.locale = es 
webui.supported.locales = en, de, es`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otIOl.png)

Any ideas of what could be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove reference the notices.
If you can't let me know.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This is a short answer that sounds like a shot in the dark

Comment: Yes @AndersonMoro it was that, I've arrived to the solution checking in the inspector. I removed top news and side news from home.jsp file and worked.